# Help finding mistake in argument about Poisson integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-functions

I believe there must be a mistake in the following argument but I am not sure where:

Suppose $f$ is harmonic in $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ such that the functions $f_{r}(\theta)=f(re^{i\theta})$ are uniformly bounded in $L^{1}([-\pi,\pi])$-norm.  Then $f(re^{i\theta})=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_{r}(\theta -t)d\mu(t)$ for some finite complex Borel measure $\mu$ on the unit circle.  (Here $P_{r}(t)$ is the Poisson kernel.  This claim can be taken for granted since I know it to be true.)  By Fatou's theorem, $d\mu=\frac{1}{2\pi}\tilde{f}d\theta+d\mu_{s}$ where $\tilde{f}(\theta)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 1}f(re^{i\theta})$ $a.e.$ and $d\mu_{s}$ and $d\theta$ (i.e. Lebesgue measure) are mutually singular.  Hence $f(re^{i\theta})=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_{r}(\theta -t)\tilde{f}(t)dt$, i.e., $f$ is the Poisson integral of $\tilde{f}\in L^{1}$ which means that $||f_{r}-\tilde{f}||_{1}\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow 1$.  But does this make sense given that we started merely with the assumption that the $||f_{r}||_{1}$ are bounded as $r\rightarrow 1$?

Comment: Well, that's part of the magic of this result, right? You start with the assumption that $f\in h^1(\mathbb{D})$ (i.e. $f$ has bounded $L^1$ averages), and conclude some nice boundary behavior. Is there a specific technical point you're iffy about?

Comment: @Jose27 it's this: so the theorem that I hinted at in the parenthetical says (i) $f_{r}$ has bounded $L^{p}$ norms for $p>1 \Leftrightarrow$ $f(z)$ is the Poisson integral of an $L^{p}$ function on the circle, (ii) the $f_{r}$ converge to a function in $L^{1} \Leftrightarrow f(z)$ is the Poisson integral of an $L^{1}$ function on the circle, (iii) $f_{r}$ has bounded $L^{1}$ norms $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(z)$ is the Poisson integral of a finite complex Borel measure on the circle.  If I am right, wouldn't that imply that (ii) and (iii) are equivalent?

Comment: There's a slight issue: First, the convergence is only a.e. on the circle, and then (ii) needs some extra condition for the $\Rightarrow$ implication: there are nontrivial harmonic functions with zero boundary values (I think there's such an example in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis"); the missing condition is exactly $f_r$ having bounded $L^1$ norms, maybe this makes the equivalence make a little more sense?